# Find the affine transformation to minimize the distance between two sets of points

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization, computational-geometry

**Definition:** Let $A=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$ two sets with the same cardinality. Then define the distance between two sets as $$d(A,B):=\min_{\sigma}\sum_i||a_i-b_{\sigma(i)}||,\text{where }\sigma \text{ is a bijection from }\{1,2,\cdots, n\} \text{ to itself}.$$

**Problem:** Given two sets of points $A$ and $B$ in the Euclidean space with the same cardinality, find the affine transformation ${\bf M}$ such that distance between the sets ${\bf M}(A)$ and $B$ is minimized, where ${\bf M}(A) = \{{\bf M} {\bf p}:{\bf p}\in A\}$.

Comment: Hi i believe you mean that $\sigma$ is a bijection from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to itself?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I've corrected it.

Comment: What sort of space do $A$ and $B$ reside in?

Comment: @Zim Euclidean space

Comment: The problem belongs to computational geometry and so it can be asked also at 
[Computer Science.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). Also in can be NP-hard.

Comment: A crude upper bound is provided by $M(A) \equiv \sum_{1\leq i\leq n}b_i/n$, although this is not sharp (e.g. demonstrated when $A=B$).

Comment: @Zim : I do not know what your comment is intended to mean.  $M(A)$ is a collection of vectors, specifically $M(A) = \{M(a_1), ..., M(a_n)\}$, so it is not the same type of thing as the single vector $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i/n$.

Comment: @Michael I meant setting $M(A)$ to be the "constant" map which sends everything to the average of the $b_i$'s will provide a rough upper bound on the minimal value of $d$

Comment: @Zim : That makes sense then.  With $A = \{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ then you mean the map is $M:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ given by the constant map $M(x) = m$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, for some $m \in \mathbb{R}^k$, in which case we have an achievable distance $dist(\{M(a_1), ..., M(a_n)\}, \{b_1, ..., b_n\})=\sum_{i=1}^n ||b_i-m||^2$, and the constant $m \in \mathbb{R}^k$ can be optimized to  $m=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i$

Answer (score 1):

Here are cases when we can achieve a distance of 0 (which must be the min distance). Fix $n, m, k$ as positive integers.  We have vectors $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ and $\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ that satisfy
\begin{align*}
&a_i \in \mathbb{R}^m \quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}\\
&b_i \in \mathbb{R}^k \quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}
\end{align*}

#### Case 1: $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ are linearly independent.

Suppose $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ are linearly independent. Then we can construct a $k \times m$ matrix $C$ that satisfies $Ca_i = b_i$ for each $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ and so $dist(\{C a_i\}_{i=1}^n, \{b_i\}_{i=1}^n)=0$.

#### Case 2: $\{(a_1;1),..., (a_n;1)\}$ are linearly independent.

For each vector $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ we can create a vector $(a_i;1)\in \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ by appending a final component of $1$. Suppose $\{(a_1;1), ..., (a_n;1)\}$ are linearly independent. Then we can construct a $k \times (m+1)$ matrix $C$ that satisfies
$$ C(a_i;1) = b_i \quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$$
Let $L$ be the last column of matrix $C$, so that $C=[D : L]$ where $D \sim k \times m$. Then
$$ C(a_i;1) = Da_i + L$$
Consider the affine mapping $M:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ by
$$ M(x) = Dx + L$$
Then $M(a_i) = Da_i+L = C(a_i;1) = b_i$ for all $i \in \{1, .., n\}$ and so $dist(\{M(a_1), ..., M(a_n)\}, \{b_1, ..,. b_n\})=0$.

Comment: An example is $\{a_1, a_2\} = \{(1,1), (2,2)\}$, which is not linearly independent, but $\{(a_1;1), (a_2;1)\} = \{(1,1,1), (2,2,1)\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Case 1 only works if $B\subset\textrm{span} A$... for instance, in $R^2$, $A=\{ (1,0) \}$ is linearly independent, but $B=\{(0,1)\}$ is not reachable by $A$.

Comment: @Zim : Case 1 works always because if $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^m$ then we can expand to a basis $\{a_1, ..., a_n, a_{n+1} , ... a_m\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^m$.  A linear map is defined by its values on a basis so we can define $M(a_i)=b_i$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ and $M(a_i)=0$ for $i>n$. Then define the full linear map as $M(\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i a_i) = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_iM(a_i)$ for all scalars $\alpha_i$.

Comment: Note also that $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ so your inclusion $B \subseteq span(A)$ does not always make sense.  In your example, by matrix multiplication, we have $(0;1) = [0 \quad 0; 1 \quad 0](1;0)$. (I don't remember the latex for writing matrices, so I write the $2 \times 2$ matrix in this 1-dimensional way).

Comment: It appears that $A$ and $B$ must reside in the same Euclidean space, otherwise $d$ is not properly defined.

Comment: There is no need to have $A$ and $B$ in the same Euclidean space because we are only computing distances betwen $\{b_1, ..., b_n\}$ and $\{M(a_1), ... M(a_n)\}$, and indeed $b_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $M(a_i)\in \mathbb{R}^k$ for all $i$.